# Getting song title and song artist only from ffprobe output

Tags: json, python-3.x, decode

So I have been working on a music player for Discordapp. The thing is I wanted to display the song title and song artist. How do I go about it

```
player = voice_stream.create_ffmpeg_player('./audio_library/1.mp3')

            # FFProbing for info
p = sp.Popen(['ffprobe', '-v', 'quiet', '-print_format', 'json=compact=1', '-show_format',
              './audio_library/1.mp3'], stdout=sp.PIPE, stderr=sp.PIPE)
op = p.communicate()
# a = dict(op)
# tit = a['title']
# art = a['artist']
# print(tit + '\n' + art)
ops = str(op)
print('op :- ' + ops)
opsn = re.sub("\r\n", "", ops)
print('opsn :- ' + opsn)
```

Thank you. Also if possible can I know how to convert this data to json format. I tried to use **json.loads(op)** but I got error saying this is a tuple.

My current output is like this:-

```
op :- (b'{\r\n    "format": { "filename": "./audio_library/1.mp3", "nb_streams": 1, "nb_programs": 0, "format_name": "mp3", "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)", "start_time": "0.000000", "duration": "351.190200", "size": "14062151", "bit_rate": "320331", "probe_score": 50,\r\n        "tags": { "title": "Rescue Me (Sigma Remix)", "artist": "Skepta", "encoded_by": "Lavf52.31.0" } }\r\n}\r\n', b'')


opsn :- (b'{\r\n    "format": { "filename": "./audio_library/1.mp3", "nb_streams": 1, "nb_programs": 0, "format_name": "mp3", "format_long_name": "MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)", "start_time": "0.000000", "duration": "351.190200", "size": "14062151", "bit_rate": "320331", "probe_score": 50,\r\n        "tags": { "title": "Rescue Me (Sigma Remix)", "artist": "Skepta", "encoded_by": "Lavf52.31.0" } }\r\n}\r\n', b'')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to get the first entry in the tuple, decode the bytes, and parse the json:

```
import json
import pprint

op_json = json.loads(op[0].decode('utf-8'))

title = op_json['format']['tags']['title']
artist = op_json['format']['tags']['artist']
print('title:', title)
print('artist:', artist)
print()
pprint.pprint(op_json)
```

Prints:

```
title: Rescue Me (Sigma Remix)
artist: Skepta

{'format': {'bit_rate': '320331',
            'duration': '351.190200',
            'filename': './audio_library/1.mp3',
            'format_long_name': 'MP2/3 (MPEG audio layer 2/3)',
            'format_name': 'mp3',
            'nb_programs': 0,
            'nb_streams': 1,
            'probe_score': 50,
            'size': '14062151',
            'start_time': '0.000000',
            'tags': {'artist': 'Skepta',
                     'encoded_by': 'Lavf52.31.0',
                     'title': 'Rescue Me (Sigma Remix)'}}}
```

Comment: should be op_json = json.loads(op[0].decode('utf-8')). Other then that its perfect. Thank you.

Comment: Fixed. Great that it helped.